# How to map a numpy array to a differently sized array based on boolean values with the rest as zeros

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This is a horribly worded question but not sure how to describe it without examples. I feel this should be really simple but have tried lots of numpy functions and not got the desired result.

Say I had two arrays:

```
a = np.array([7, 3])
b = np.array([True, False, True, False])
```

How could I combine these using numpy methods to get the resultant array `c`:

```
c = np.array([7, 0, 3, 0])
```

Obviously this is an overly simplified example but, in theory, my arrays could be very large.

Comment: Docs should help - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Comment: it goes without saying I have been looking at the docs...

Comment: If you've looked at the docs, what have you tried to solve your own problem?  Please review [ask], which clarifies that you should include an [mcve] that shows your attempt.

Comment: about 10 different ways, which have all been unsuccessful. I don't see how this would help the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [283]: a = np.array([7, 3]) 
     ...: b = np.array([True, False, True, False])
```

What the comments were trying to get you to try and or show is indexing operations like this:

```
In [284]: c = np.zeros(b.shape, int)                                                                         
In [285]: c[b] = a                                                                                           
In [286]: c                                                                                                  
Out[286]: array([7, 0, 3, 0])
```

The boolean mask applied to `c` produces array of the selected values:

```
In [287]: c[b]                                                                                               
Out[287]: array([7, 3])
```

Comment: great thank you! Yes, I knew what they were getting at but I had a bunch of incoherent attempts, none of which I'd really kept track of. Haha knew it should be this simple